# JSON Object Array of Properties

Tags: javascript, json, properties

I've been trying to figure out this particular object for quite a while and it's frustrating me endlessly so I was hoping to get it resolved here.

I have an object that looks like this:

```
options = {
    headers: {
        rows: [
            cols = {
                text: "Blah",
                span: 12,
                color: "#FFF"
            }
        ],
        [
            cols = {
                text: "Blah2",
                span: 8,
                color: "#FFF"
            }
            cols = {
                text: "Blah2",
                span: 4,
                color: "#FFF"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

With the intended result being an object that can be used to populate header rows above a table using a combination of the text, span, and color properties (with a few additions for later) to customize styling it properly.

I'm going for:

```
var text = options.headers.rows[x].cols[y].text;
```

Such that a nested loop can generate out the headers. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Mmh, you have an error in your object, `{headers: {rows: [...], <here> [...]}}` are you missing a property name here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [[See it in action](http://jsbin.com/ocipo3/3/)]

```
var options = {
    headers: {
        rows: [ // Array
        { // row: 0
            cols: [ // Array
            { // col: 0
                text: "Blah",
                span: 12,
                color: "#FFF"
            },
            { // col: 1
                text: "Blah2",
                span: 8,
                color: "#FFF"
            },
            { // col: 2
                text: "Blah2",
                span: 4,
                color: "#FFF"
            }]
        },
        { // row: 1
            cols: [ // Array
            { // col: 0
                text: "Blah",
                span: 12,
                color: "#FFF"
            },
            { // col: 1
                text: "Blah2",
                span: 4,
                color: "#FFF"
            }]
        }]
    }
};
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, I am going to add the comments from the source view of that jsbin so that I can understand what was done here.